# Computing invariant subspace of matrix group algorithmically

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, representation-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

I am given a finite set of orthogonal matrices $T_1,...,T_m\in\mathrm{O}(n)$, and I wonder how to *compute* a basis of an invariant subspace, i.e. a subspace $V\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ so that for all $i\in\{1,...,m\}$ we have

$$v\in V\;\implies\; T_iv\in V.$$

**Notes**

- I am looking for an *algorithm* to do this computationally!
- Actually, the orthogonal matrices are given to me via a (reducible) linear representation $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$ of a finit group $G$. So the algorithm might use that the matrices form a matrix group. Especially, I am given $\rho$ as a black box function and $G$ by some generators.
- It would be especially nice if the invariant subspace would be minimal, but as long as it is proper and non-zero I can live with that.

Comment: Would $G$ be a finite group? (i.e. do all of the $T_i$ have finite order?)

Comment: @Joppy Yes, $G$ is a finite group.

Comment: Do you know what the group is explicitly? Do you know its character table?

Comment: @DavidHill I am working with Mathematica, so I have access to everything that Mathematica supports. I am not sure about the character table. The group is given by some permutations that generate the group. I can compute all elements, but this would be inefficient, right?

Comment: If you know the character table, there are formulas for projections onto subrepresentations. @Joppy asked a question about this under the rt tag a day or so ago. Another possibility is to use meataxe on GAP, but that may require a finite field.

Comment: @DavidHill those projection formulas are a sum over elements of $G$, and $|G|$ might be gigantic compared to $\dim V$. So without doing something clever, this doesn’t yield a practical algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

From $n = 5$, the subgroups of $O(n)$ may be very complicated.

Firstly, we can have a look on the common invariant subspaces of $2$ matrices $A,B\in M_n$ where $A$ has simple eigenvalues; yet, the known algorithm (cf. M. Tsatsomeros or A. Georges-K.D. Ikramov) has exponential complexity and works only until $n=12$.

Here you know a generator of $G$ that is constituted with permutations $\sigma$ (if I correctly understand). Then it "suffices" to know how to obtain the invariant spaces of such a permutation matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]$ where $a_{\sigma(i),i}=1$. We can decompose $\sigma=c_1\circ\cdots\circ\sigma_k$ in disjoint cycles (with the cycles of length $1$). Then $\mathbb{R}^n=U_1\oplus\cdots\oplus U_k$ where $U_i$ is generated by the vectors of the canonical basis of indices $support(c_i)$ and, of course, is invariant; moreover $\chi_{A|_{U_i}}=x^l_i-1 $ (characteristic polynomial) where $l_i$ is the length of $c_i$. The eigenvalues of $A_{|U_i}$ are simple; so the invariant (real) subspaces of $A_{|U_i}$ are those generated by the eigenvectors associated to any subset $W$ of $Roots(x^l_i-1)$ under the condition that if $\lambda\in W$, then $\overline{\lambda}\in W$.

Among the invariant subspaces of $A$, there are the direct sums of the above susbspaces; unfortunately we don't obtain  the entire set of invariant subspaces of $A$ (except if $k=1$; in particular, the first thing to do is to verify if some generator is a cycle; if yes, then the problem is solved because this generator has only a finite number of invariant spaces). Indeed, there are $2$ problems:

Firstly, the eigenvalue $1$ is common to each $i\leq k$. Then if $k>1$, then there are an infinity of invariant spaces.

Secondly, there may exist other common factors between some of the $\chi_{A|_{U_i}}$ (for example, if $2$ cycles have same length).